# is there a way to use postcss with styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs, postcss, styled-components

is there a way to use postcss with styled-components when styling React.js components?
I'm using postcss plugins like px-to-rem and rucksack css responsive fonts which are amazing and I would hate to give those up. Is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: see https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/62

Comment: i have read it and it is very vague. if this is the only source to refer to as relevant, I'd say that the answer is no, there is no way to use postcss plugins when using styled components but maybe just maybe it will be possible in the future... did I get it wrong? since it is quite an eco-system of plugins people worked hard to develop and rely in their projects that are being asked to sacrifice for being able to use styled-components...

Answer (score 0):

At the moment no as in [this issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/482).

Max Stoiber from stytled components said on more than one occasion that these tools should be JS functions and not more tooling. On [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaqDA7Btm3c) if I'm not mistaken. The good news is that they are trying to port it already.

> We're working on a "standard library" that'll contain all sorts of useful functions like px2rem. This will be released soon, it's almost done

So in a nutshell if you need something like that right now you probably should find the function that does that on postCss and use it yourself.

Another option would be to have a mixed approach for the moment with postCss for these stuff and passing the styled-component class as well as the postCss class.